# How to match two CSV files by awk?

Tags: awk

I have two CSV files as

```
ID1,V1,V2,V3,V4
1,4,5,3,3
2,66,77,46,44
3,66,77,46,44

ID2,V1,V2,V3,V4
55,4,5,3,3
84,66,77,46,44
```

How can I get a CSV of

```
ID1,ID2
1,55
2,84
3,84
```

by matching `V1,V2,V3,V4` blocks in two CSV files?

The purpose is to reproduce `file1` by replacing `V1,V2,V3,V4` with its corresponding `ID2` value from `file2`. In other words, the number of lines in the `result` file is the same as `file1`.

`ID1` and `ID2` are unique and ordered, `ID1,ID2` will be unique too. The files are well-formatted. Only digits separated by `,` in five columns shown.

The files are quite large (1B lines), and this is the reason I need a high-performance approach like `awk`.

The solution given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132675/two-csv-files-compare-using-awk) should be applicable, but it was the opposite join (common ID), and I couldn't adapt it to my case.

Comment: Search on SO: `awk NR!=FNR`, there's tons of responses

Comment: The approach taken in the answer to the linked question should also work in your case, what have you got so far?

Comment: The referenced solution requires to keep an in-memory index of every unique (V1,V2,V3,V4) combination from one of the files. (a) If every such combination is unique, a billion-entry index is probably excessive. (b) If they are non-unique, we don't know what to do with multiple mappings. Probably sorting both files on cols 2-5, and merging, is indicated, but we need to know how to deal with any duplicates.

Comment: So we can see how multiple matches and no-matches are handled, please [edit] your question to include the following lines in your input and add the expected output when those lines are present in the input: file1 add `3,4,5,3,3` and `4,9,8,7,6`; file2 add `85,66,77,46,44`, `86,4,5,3,3` and `87,6,7,8,9`.

Comment: Saying `1B lines` is ambiguous btw, assuming B means billion, since 1 billion in some countries is 1 million million (i.e. `1,000,000,000,000`) but in others is 1 thousand million (i.e. `1,000,000,000)` which are obviously 2 vastly different numbers. See short scale vs long scale and the current usage map at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will be fast and only the `sort` part stores any significant amount in memory and it's built to do do paging, etc. handle that and so should be fine:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# First awk output is hdrFlag,fileNr,ID,VALs1-4 then we sort on
# the hdrFlag to handle the header line first, then the key values
# so we can process all matching keys together from both input
# files so we only have to store the IDs for the current key set.
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==1{++fileNr} {print (FNR>1), fileNr, $0}' "$@" |
sort -t, -k1,1n -k4 |
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    {
        curr = $4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7
        if ( curr != prev ) {
            prt()
            prev = curr
        }
        ids[$2] = ($2 in ids ? ids[$2] " " : "") $3
    }
    END { prt() }

    function prt(       file,numFiles) {
        for (file in ids) {
            numFiles++
        }
        if (numFiles > 1) {
            print ids[1], ids[2]
        }
        delete ids
    }
'
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh file1 file2
ID1,ID2
1,55
2,84
```

I'm just guessing at how you'd want to handle cases where there are multiple matches between the files for the same set of 4 values.

Comment: it returns `ID1 ID1 ID1,ID2` when there is a duplicate, right? For example, `1 2 3,55` as I need to split it to `1,55\n2,55\n3,55`.

Comment: Right, just change the `print ids[1], ids[2]` line to `split()` each of the 2 strings currently being printed and loop on their contents to get the pairs listed individually. Edit your question per [my earlier comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589901/how-to-match-two-csv-files-by-awk/590018#comment1099643_589901) to show how duplicates, etc. should be handled if you need more help.

Comment: sorry, I did not see your comment, as I read your second comment. I edited the question per your suggestion.